# Datatable column name omits names starting with a number

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, datatable

So my sql query is

```
  List<string> names = new List<string>();    
  cmd = new SqlCommand("Select " + string.Join(",", names) + " from test");
  da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
  dt = new DataTable();
  da.Fill(dt);
```

When it fills the data table there are column names beginning with a number and it omits the number and just prints the text after

For example,
if the Column name was "1AB2C"
it become "AB2C".
Can someone tell me why this happens and where is it getting modified?

Comment: pad your columns with [ and ] example: [1AB2C]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the SQL standards, table names cannot start with a number.
See this post for further information: [Table or column name cannot start with numeric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917064/table-or-column-name-cannot-start-with-numeric)

Comment: you have to use quotes ` before the table name. eg: SELECT * FROM ` 2names `

Comment: or you can change your naming convention. For example you can use and underscore before the table name or a prefix like "tbl_"

Comment: i really can't do that. It is actually a data value.

Comment: try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254009/in-c-add-quotes-around-string-in-a-comma-delimited-list-of-strings

Comment: I did use single quotes. But that does not work and the data table does not have any column names now.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
            names.Add("[1col]"); //you may write your
            names.Add("name");
            string[] arr = names.ToArray();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select " + String.Join(",", arr) + " from test");
```